# gcloud node api for replacing vms in an instance group not working, but equivalent command line action does

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, gce-instance-group

I am trying to programmatically replace VMs in my instance group. This gcloud commandline run within the cloud shell successfully replaces the instances:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action start-update INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME --version=template=TEMPLATE_NAME --zone=ZONE --type='proactive' --max-surge=1 --max-unavailable=0 --minimal-action='replace' --most-disruptive-allowed-action='replace' --replacement-method='substitute'
```

However, the equivalent node code logs as a successful patch operation (just like the gcloud command does) but the VMs never are replaced (ie nothing happens to my VMs):

```
            const { InstanceGroupManagersClient } = require('@google-cloud/compute');
            const instanceGroupManagerResource = {
            versions: [ {
                instanceTemplate: "global/instanceTemplates/TEMPLATE_NAME"
            } ],
            updatePolicy: {
                type: 'PROACTIVE',
                minimalAction: 'REPLACE',
                mostDisruptiveAllowedAction: 'REPLACE',
                maxSurge: {
                    fixed: 1 // Number of additional instances that can be created during the update
                },
                maxUnavailable: {
                    fixed: 0 // Number of instances that can be unavailable during the update
                },
                replacementMethod: 'SUBSTITUTE' // Method for instance replacement
            }
        };

        // Perform the patch operation
        const [operation] = await instanceGroupManagersClient.patch({
            project: project,
            zone: zone,
            instanceGroupManager: instanceGroupManager,
            instanceGroupManagerResource: instanceGroupManagerResource,
        });
```

I've tried a ton of different variations here, but nothing has worked. Here's the best resource from google I could find:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups#replacement_method

Can someone help?

Comment: Please add details to explain "isn't working" in your question. You could try adding `--log-http` to the `gcloud` command to see the specific underlying API calls that are being made by the command.

Comment: Updated to be a bit more specific. The operations logs weren’t very descriptive, so didn’t include. Hopefully someone has run into a similar issue!

Comment: 1. Even the `Patch` operation completes successfully with status DONE, the VM update may still being replaced. Have you tried to query using listManagedInstances method (or check in console later)? 2. Can you update your library import code as `const {InstanceGroupManagersClient} = require('@google-cloud/compute').v1;` to avoid using beta version. 3. For `minimalAction: 'REPLACE'` update policy, can you try with *`minimalAction: 'REFRESH'`*? This ensures that minimalAction is surely less disruptive than the `mostDisruptiveAllowedAction`.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! I wound up taking a different approach of using cloud build. Additionally, I realized I needed this command instead:
compute instance-groups managed rolling-action replace maingroup --zone=us-west1-b --max-surge=1 --max-unavailable=0 --replacement-method=substitute